# How Can I Prevent Flutter Dio Package Inceptors From Entering Infinite Loop?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I want to make the toki refresh by using the inceptors in the Flutter Dio package.

I use the onError method to make it request again, but even though I use handler.reject(e) it goes into an infinite loop.

```
class DioFetch {
  Dio dio = Dio();

  DioFetch() {
    demoInceptor();
  }

  demoInceptor() async {
    dio.interceptors.clear();
    dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest: (options, handler) {
          print("onRequest");
          return handler.next(options);
        },
        onError: (DioError e, handler) async {
          if (e.response != null) {
            if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
              print("statuscode: 401");
              final refresh = await refreshToken();
              if (refresh.statusCode == 200) {
                RequestOptions options = e.requestOptions;
                try {
                  var resp = await dio.request(e.requestOptions.path,
                      data: options.data,
                      cancelToken: options.cancelToken,
                      onReceiveProgress: options.onReceiveProgress,
                      onSendProgress: options.onSendProgress,
                      queryParameters: options.queryParameters);
                  return handler.resolve(resp);
                } on DioError catch (error) {
                  return handler.reject(error);
                }
              } else {
                return handler.reject(e);
              }
            }
          } else {
            return handler.next(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Response> refreshToken() async {
    //refresh token code. response dio
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://pub.dev/packages/dio_smart_retry/versions/1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it in two ways

1- return `error` instead of `handler.reject(e);`

2- Don't use the same `dio` instance

- Create another interceptor for token refreshing:

  ```
  class TokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {

      TokenInterceptor()
          : dio = Dio(
        BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: EndPoints.baseUrl,
        ),
      )..interceptors.addAll([
        if (kDebugMode) PrettyDioLogger(),
      ]);

      final Dio dio;

      @override
      void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
        // Do whatever you want
      }
    }
  ```
- Add it to the app dio client:

  ```
  dio = Dio()
  ..interceptors.addAll([
    TokenInterceptor(),
  ]);
  ```